# Unexpected behavior with Stream.CopyToAsync ( DeflateStream )

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream

I am hoping that I wont have to copy the full example or create a minimal solution and the issue is some basic knowledge problem of mine.

I have a application that syncs data with Azure Storage, it all works fine and the upload part is already in a Async Method. It all works.

I was trying to optimize alittle more and wanted to change a stream.CopyTo to a CopyToAsync.

```
using(var filestream = streamProvider())
{
    filestream.CopyTo(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
}
```

I changed it to await filestream.CopyToAsync(stream) and only parts of my files are upload.

At the point of writing I found out that the Exception throw is a "Found invalid data while decoding", IO.InvalidDataException.

This lead me back to the stream being a GZip/ or DeflateStream - so guess my question is about if its not expected to work with CopyToAsync on those kind of streams?

#### Context

```
public async Task UploadFile(string storePath, Func<Stream> streamProvider, bool copyLocalBeforeUpload = false)
{
    using (new Timer(this.MessageQueue, "UPLOAD", storePath))
    {
        using (var stream =  copyLocalBeforeUpload ? new MemoryStream() : streamProvider() )
        {
            try
            {
                if (copyLocalBeforeUpload)
                {
                    using (var filestream = streamProvider())
                    {
                        await filestream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;
                    }
                }

                var blob = GetBlobReference(storePath);
            
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream,new BlobRequestOptions { RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 3) });        

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (this.MessageQueue != null)
                {
                    this.MessageQueue.Enqueue(string.Format("Failed uploading '{0}'", storePath));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you could show more context here.

Comment: I dont belive the context makes a difference, but i will add the full method instead.

Comment: There will be alot of tasks trying to copy at the same time, the streamProvider is a ZipArchiveEntry.Open delegate -> wondering if that could cause the issue, that many readers are trying to read from the same zip file at the same time.

Comment: Well surely that's the first thing to diagnose: if you do this with just a single thread, do you still have the problem?